# what is wrong with this LEFT JOIN/SELECT? (the SELECT alone works, and the LEFT JOIN wthout SELECT also work)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery, left-join

MS Access

tables:

```
prodcuts:
+----+---------+
| id | p_name  |
+----+---------+
warehouses:
+----+--------+
| id | w_name |
+----+--------+
how_many_should_be:
+--------------+------------+----------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | how_many |
+--------------+------------+----------+
intake
+--------------+------------+---------------+
| warehouse_id | product_id | intake_amount |
+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

the wanted query result:

```
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+
| w_name | p_name | how_many_should_be | intake_sum |
+--------+--------+--------------------+------------+
```

this is the query:
it works fine if i leaveout the "LEFT JOIN", and the SLELET in the LEFT JOIN works fine if put in a query by itself. os i d'ont understand what's wrong.

```
SELECT
warehouses.w_name AS [w_name],
products.p_name AS [p_name],
how_many_should_be.how_many AS [how_many_should_be]



FROM (((how_many_should_be INNER JOIN warehouses ON how_many_should_be.warehouse_id = warehouses.id)

INNER JOIN products ON how_many_should_be.product_id = products.id)

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT intake.warehouse_id, intake.product_id, Sum(intake.units_amout) AS [intake_sum]
     FROM intake
     GROUP BY intake.warehouse_id, intake.product_id)
ON how_many_should_be.warehouse_id = intake.warehouse_id)

ORDER BY warehouses.w_name, products.p_name
```

the error: "syntax error on JOIN operation"

Comment: I think you need aliases on the subqueris.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff OK. now with the alias it is showing all INTAKE_SUM on EVERY record

Comment: UPDATE: i added "how_many_should_be.product_id = intake.product_id" and it did work! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a poster previously mentioned you need to alias the subquery correctly and make sure to update any JOIN and SELECT statements. Here's what it would look like (I rewrote the INNER JOINS for my own purposes, feel free to keep yours as is, it shouldn't impact the final result):

```
SELECT
warehouses.w_name AS [w_name],
products.p_name AS [p_name],
how_many_should_be.how_many AS [how_many_should_be],
Agg_Intake.[intake_sum] -- pull in the SUM from the sub query
FROM warehouses
INNER JOIN how_many_should_be 
    ON how_many_should_be.warehouse_id = warehouses.id
INNER JOIN products 
    ON how_many_should_be.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT intake.warehouse_id, intake.product_id, Sum(intake.units_amout) AS [intake_sum]
     FROM intake
     GROUP BY intake.warehouse_id, intake.product_id
     ) Agg_Intake -- the needed alias for the subquery
    ON how_many_should_be.warehouse_id = Agg_Intake.warehouse_id -- join ON the aliased subquery.column name
ORDER BY warehouses.w_name, products.p_name
```